# Order of references, tables/figures, and appendices using apa6 class

Tags: apa-style, apa6

According to APA 6th edition, the order of a manuscript should be: Title Page, Abstract, Body, References, Footnotes, Tables, Figures, Appendixes. I am trying to typeset a manuscript with the class apa6 with apacite reference style, but the order of the last few parts doesn't seem to follow this. After the body (ignoring footnotes for now), it produced an order of tables/figures, appendix, reference. Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass[man,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\title{This is the title}
\author{Joe Williams}
\affiliation{University A}
\leftheader{Left header}
\abstract{This is the abstract}
\keywords{APA style}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Content of the article.
This is what we cite \cite{Smith2013}.
Table~\ref{tab:the_able} has some info.

\begin{table}
\caption{A complex table.}
\label{tab:the_able}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
cell 1 & cell 2 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\appendix

\section{The Appendix}
Stuff I want to put in the appendix.

\bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

whereas the file "ref.bib" has the following content.

```
@article{Smith2013,
    Author = {Smith, A.},
    Journal = {Psychological Review},
    Number = {1},
    Pages = {23-45},
    Title = {{This is the title}},
    Volume = {6},
    Year = {2013}}
```

How can I fix this? Or, is there a way to arbitrarily reorder these different parts?

Comment: How about moving `\bibliography{ref}` before the `\begin{table}`?

Comment: this kind of violates my sense of ordering, because I feel like the reference command should not be in the middle of the text. But a variation of this worked: basically, if I put `\bibliography{ref}` before `\appendix` then it worked. I didn't think this would help because I need the order to be R-TF-A (for reference, tables/figures, appendix), but it was in TF-A-R. But for some reason, moving the references in front of the appendix somehow moved it in front of tables/figures too. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: that's great, glad you've got a solution :) is the issue resolved? if so, you could either post your answer, or else we can close the question as too localized- your choice :)

Comment: I guess I will answer my own question then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if I put `\bibliography{ref}` before `\appendix`, it would change the order from TF-A-R (for tables/figures, appendix, reference) to R-TF-A, for whatever reason.